# Querying another model from inside a model created by FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, bdd, factory-bot

Just starting with FactoryGirl. I have a Model named `Subscription`. It has a method 'set_price` which apparently does some calculations. In order to do so, it has to ask another model for some values:

```
def set_price
  base_price = Option.find_by_key(:base_price).value.to_f
  # […] some calculations
end
```

When running my specs I get:

```
   NoMethodError:
            undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
```

Which is quite logical since I didn't (yet?) create any `Options`.

Is `FactoryGirl` suited for this? Do I have to create `Option` fixtures in this case? Or just mock it?

Comment: Is there a `:has_many, :through` relationship between the two models?

Comment: @SteveRowley nope. They are not related at all - besides for this particular method.

Comment: Ok - if they were related I'd say you could possibly do it without mocking, but if not, I agree with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail because there are no Options in the database. You can either create the option factory before calling set_price in the test (you'll need to make sure find_by_key(:base_price) will return your factory created option in this case), or you can as you say use a mock:

```
option = mock_model('Option', :value => 1)
Option.stub(:find_by_key).and_return(option)
```

The mock has the advantage that it will not touch the database, but it's potentially more brittle.